# How to use gulp and babel to compile .jsx files to .js?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, gulp, babeljs

I'm not entirely sure how to use babel and gulp and to compile some react jsx files to JavaScript.

I've installed nodejs, `babel-cli`, `gulp-babel`, `babel-preset-react`, and `babel-preset-es2015`

The node modules appeared in my working directory and everything seems to be there.

My `package.json` file looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "example1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "babel":{
    "presets": ["react", "es2015"]
  },
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.7.5",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "gulp-babel": "^6.1.2"
  }
}
```

And my `gulpfile.js` looks like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var react = require('gulp-react');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var babel = require("gulp-babel");

gulp.task('default', function(){
    return gulp.src('src/**').pipe(react()).pipe(concat('application.js')).pipe(gulp.dest(' ./'))
});
```

I believe this is all the setup required to be able to compile my files to JavaScript. However from the command prompt when I try `npm run gulp`, I get the following output which I'm not sure how to interpret:

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "gulp"
npm ERR! node v4.4.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.0

npm ERR! missing script: gulp
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Cossie\Desktop\INFO30005 mockup\react\Example 1\npm-debug.log
```

What can I do to make my .jsx react files compile to .js?

EDIT:

Adding `"gulp":"gulp"` under scripts in `package.json` and then running `npm run gulp` gives me:

```
module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'gulp-react'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Cossie\Desktop\INFO30005 mockup\react\Example 1\gulpfile.js:2:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "gulp"
npm ERR! node v4.4.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! example1@1.0.0 gulp: `gulp`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the example1@1.0.0 gulp script 'gulp'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the example1 package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     gulp
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs example1
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!
npm ERR!     npm owner ls example1
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Cossie\Desktop\INFO30005 mockup\react\Example 1\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: if you have gulp install globally just run `gulp` instead of `npm run gulp`

Comment: @AlexeyB. gulp is only installed locally

Comment: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run gulp from a project-local installation using `npm run gulp` you have to add a `gulp` script to your `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  "gulp": "gulp"
},
```

Comment: I did this and got some more errors. See my edit, seems it can't find gulp-react but I'm sure that I installed it with babel. Have I missed anything?

Comment: Doesn't look like you installed it, otherwise it would appear among the  `"devDependencies"` in your `package.json`. Just run `npm install --save-dev gulp-react`. Same for any other dependencies you might be missing.